# Cross language reversible encryption (PHP, Python)

Tags: php, python, passwords, password-encryption

I have a PHP driven web form that I would like to be able to input a password, encrypt it, and load it into a database.  Then, using Python, query that password, decrypt it, and then use it to authenticate to a Microsoft Exchange email server with SMTPLIB.  The rest of the authentication information will be stored in plain text.  My main goal is to not store the password in plain text.

The only reason I am trying to use both languages is that the rest of the 'work' for my program is done in Python.  I only use PHP for a simple interface.  It is only for consistency.

Is there a simple to use, cross language reversible encryption library that can be used for this?

Would I be better off making my email script in PHP?  If this is the case what library would be recommended for this task?

Comment: While I can't comment on cross-language reversible encryption, I can confirm that sending emails in php is easy and doesn't require a library - see the `mail()` function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php
You can specify headers with 4th parameter, and you can send HTML code (see example #4 on the documentation page).

Comment: All popular encrypted algorythms is described by standarts. Different languages have the same end implementation. For example md5 hash will be the same and for PHP and for Python. No matter which language you use.

Comment: You could encrypt it in the database layer rather than the application layer? There's not really specific enough information here, as to what you're doing, to give a fuller answer.

Comment: @quinxorin The only reason I would like to use Python over PHP is the rest of the 'work' for my program is done in Python.  It just makes it easier that way.

Comment: @Denis Do you have a recommendation that is well supported for both Python and PHP?

Comment: @CD001 What information is needed to clear things up?

Comment: @Butters http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1321.txt standard one for all languages

Comment: @Butters what is it that your script is trying to do - is it a sendmail application? What is the password for, a mail server - if so, where's the rest of the connection/authentication data? Why do you need to pass it from PHP to Python? Do you need the password encrypting or would a salted hash be better? If you're trying to do a mass-mailer, I'd avoid PHP for the send operation (unless you want to get into the IMAP extension). I guess the crux of it really is whether you **need** to be able to read the password or not.

Comment: @Denis Isn't MD5 a hashing algorithm, not an encryption algorithm, therefore not decryptable?

Comment: @CD001 Question updated, I think you will find all the answers there.

Comment: @CD001: I second that, if it is a mass mailing application, Python smtp module + celery (for queue management) is the way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you **need** to read the password back, do encryption at the Database layer rather than the application layer - just ensure that you're connecting to the database either locally or over SSL.

To store the password the steps would be something like:

- Computer >>
- HTTPS >>
- Web server (PHP form) >>
- (HTTPS if on a different server >>)
- database (AES Encryption)

Depending on the database you're using the syntax will probably change, but with MySQL you can do something like:

```
INSERT INTO `table` (`password`) 
VALUES (AES_ENCRYPT('{$sPassword}', '{$sEncryptionKey}'))
```

Since PHP is writing this to the database you can use a PDO prepared statement to get the data in there...

To retrieve the password with your Python script you'll simply need to run a SELECT statement on the SQL server with something like (assuming the data is in an AES encrypted BLOB) this:

```
SELECT CONVERT(AES_DECRYPT(`table`.`password`, '{$sEncryptionKey}') USING 'utf8')
AS `password`
```

This way the **only** common data you need between PHP and Python is the encryption key (which is just a string). As long as you maintain an SSL connection whenever you're passing this data across the Internet, you should be OK.

Answer (score 0):

AES symmetric encryption:

- python you need pycrypto (https://www.dlitz.net/software/pycrypto/)
- PHP does have AES support trough mcrypt (http://php.net/manual/en/book.mcrypt.php) or there are some pure PHP implementations ex: http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/